# How to parse Google custom search javascript output in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to fetch some articles from [ACL website](https://aclanthology.org/) based on the keywords as input. The website is using google custom search API and the output of the API is a javascript object.

How I can parse the returned object in python and fetch the article name, URL, and abstract of the research paper from the object.

The script I am using to fetch articles :

```
import requests


params = (
    ('rsz', 'filtered_cse'),
    ('num', '10'),
    ('hl', 'en'),
    ('source', 'gcsc'),
    ('gss', '.com'),
    ('cselibv', 'cc267ab8871224bd'),
    ('cx', '000299513257099441687:fkkgoogvtaw'),
    ('q', 'multi-label text classification'),
    ('safe', 'off'),
    ('cse_tok', 'AJvRUv1dd6NHqw5GKAoRSg3lLILE:1636278007905'),
    ('sort', ''),
    ('exp', 'csqr,cc,4618906'),
    ('callback', 'google.search.cse.api12760'),
)

response = requests.get('https://cse.google.com/cse/element/v1', params=params)

print(response.headers['Content-Type'])
# 'application/javascript; charset=utf-8'
```

output looks like this:

```
'/*O_o*/\ngoogle.search.cse.api12760({\n  "cursor": {\n    "currentPageIndex": 0,\n    "estimatedResultCount": "21600",\n    "moreResultsUrl": "http://www.google.com/cse?oe=utf8&ie=utf8&source=uds&q=multi-label+text+classification&safe=off&sort=&cx=000299513257099441687:fkkgoogvtaw&start=0",\n    "resultCount": "21,600",\n    "searchResultTime": "0.16",\n    "pages": [\n      {\n        "label": 1,\n        "start": "0"\n      },\n      {\n        "label": 2,\n        "start": "10"\n      },\n      {\n        "label":
```

Although the output in the network tab of chrome is JSON while initiating the [search command](https://aclanthology.org/search/?q=multi-label%20text%20classification):

[image]

How can I get articles along with their link from the js object in python?

Comment: I hope this article will help you [click here to navigate](https://medium.com/@rifaislamet1509/solved-scraping-all-of-data-from-google-cse-using-python-13d3e6f12413)

Comment: maybe if you skip `callback` then it will send it as pure JSON and you could use module `json` to convert it to Python dictionary. At this moment you may remove from string `/*O_o*/\ngoogle.search.cse.api12760(` and `);` at the end and you should have `JSON` which you can convert to Python dictionary.

Comment: Do you really need to grab the abstract portion ?if so, then you can do that using automation tool something like selenium. Because api isn't producing the  full data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`response.text` gives you string and if you remove `/*O_o*/\ngoogle.search.cse.api12760(` at the beginning, and `);` at the end then you will have normal `JSON` which you can convert to Python dictionary using `json.loads()` - and then you can use `[key]` to get data from dictionary.

---

Minimal working example

```
import requests
import json

params = (
    ('rsz', 'filtered_cse'),
    ('num', '10'),
    ('hl', 'en'),
    ('source', 'gcsc'),
    ('gss', '.com'),
    ('cselibv', 'cc267ab8871224bd'),
    ('cx', '000299513257099441687:fkkgoogvtaw'),
    ('q', 'multi-label text classification'),
    ('safe', 'off'),
    ('cse_tok', 'AJvRUv1dd6NHqw5GKAoRSg3lLILE:1636278007905'),
    ('sort', ''),
    ('exp', 'csqr,cc,4618906'),
    ('callback', 'google.search.cse.api12760'),
)

response = requests.get('https://cse.google.com/cse/element/v1', params=params)

start = len('''/*O_o*/
google.search.cse.api12760(''')
end = len(');')

text = response.text[start:-end]
data = json.loads(text)

#print(data)

for item in data['results']:
    #print('keys:', item.keys())
    print('title:', item['title'])
    print('url:', item['url'])
    #print('content:', item['content'])
    #print('title:', item['titleNoFormatting'])
    #meta = item['richSnippet']['metatags']
    #if 'author' in meta:
    #    print('author:', meta['author'])
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
title: Large-Scale <b>Multi</b>-<b>Label Text Classification</b> on EU Legislation - ACL ...
url: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P19-1636/
---
title: <b>Label</b>-Specific Document Representation for <b>Multi</b>-<b>Label Text</b> ...
url: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D19-1044/
---
title: Initializing neural networks for hierarchical <b>multi</b>-<b>label text</b> ...
url: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W17-2339
---
title: TaxoClass: Hierarchical <b>Multi</b>-<b>Label Text Classification</b> Using Only ...
url: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/2021.naacl-main.335/
---
title: NeuralClassifier: An Open-source Neural Hierarchical <b>Multi</b>-<b>label</b> ...
url: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P19-3015/
---
title: Extreme <b>Multi</b>-<b>Label</b> Legal <b>Text Classification</b>: A Case Study in EU ...
url: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W19-2209
---
title: Hierarchical Transfer Learning for <b>Multi</b>-<b>label Text Classification</b> ...
url: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P19-1633/
---
title: Global Model for Hierarchical <b>Multi</b>-<b>Label Text Classification</b> - ACL ...
url: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/I13-1006
---
title: Hierarchical <b>Multi</b>-<b>label Classification</b> of <b>Text</b> with Capsule Networks ...
url: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P19-2045
---
title: Improving Pretrained Models for Zero-shot <b>Multi</b>-<b>label Text</b> ...
url: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/2021.naacl-main.83.pdf
---
```

---

**BTW:**

If you display `item.keys()` then you should see what else you can get:

```
'cacheUrl', 'clicktrackUrl', 'content', 'contentNoFormatting', 
'title', 'titleNoFormatting', 'formattedUrl', 'unescapedUrl', 'url', 
'visibleUrl', 'richSnippet', 'breadcrumbUrl'
```

Or you can use for-loop to display all keys and values

```
for item in data['results']:
    for key, value in item.items():
        print(f'{key}: {value}')
        print('---')
    print('===================================')
```

Some of them may have sub dictionaries - like `item['richSnippet']['metatags']['author']`